# Fastest way to ingest data from BigQuery to PubSub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

At the moment I am going through the GCP docs trying to figure out what is the optimal/fastest way to ingest data from BigQuery (using Python) to PubSub. What I am doing so far (in a simplified way) is:

```
MESSAGE_SIZE_IN_BYTES = 500
MAX_BATCH_MESSAGES = 20
MAX_BYTES_BATCH = MESSAGE_SIZE_IN_BYTES * MAX_BATCH_MESSAGES
BATCH_MAX_LATENCY_IN_10MS = 0.01
MAX_FLOW_MESSAGES = 20
MAX_FLOW_BYTES = MESSAGE_SIZE_IN_BYTES * MAX_FLOW_MESSAGES

batch_settings = pubsub_v1.types.BatchSettings(
    max_messages=MAX_BATCH_MESSAGES,
    max_bytes=MAX_BYTES_BATCH,
    max_latency=BATCH_MAX_LATENCY_IN_10MS,
)
publisher_options = pubsub_v1.types.PublisherOptions(
    flow_control=pubsub_v1.types.PublishFlowControl(
        message_limit=MAX_FLOW_MESSAGES,
        byte_limit=MAX_FLOW_BYTES,
        limit_exceeded_behavior=pubsub_v1.types.LimitExceededBehavior.BLOCK,
    ),
)
pubsub_client = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(credentials=credentials,
                                 batch_settings=self.batch_settings,       
             publisher_options=self.publisher_options)

bigquery_client = ....

bq_query_job = bigquery_client.query(QUERY)
rows = bq_query_job.result()
for row in rows:
    callback_obj = PubsubCallback(...)
    json_data = json.dumps(row).encode("utf-8")
    publish_future = pubsub_client.publish(topic_path, json_data)
    publish_future.add_done_callback(callback_obj.callback)
    publish_futures.append(publish_future)
```

so one message per row. I have being trying to tweak different params for the PubSub publisher client etc, but I cannot get further than 20/30 messages(rows) per second. Is there a way to read from BigQuery using Pubsub in a faster way (at least 1000 times faster than now)?

Comment: You are only batching 20 messages per call. Increase that number. Basically, you want to be batching 1 MB of messages when possible. The value **BATCH_MAX_LATENCY_IN_10MS** is way too small.

Comment: I played with different numbers to be fair, 200, 1000 messages per call etc but not real gain as it seems stuck to the 20/30 messages per sec

Comment: What looks to me the problem, is how the data is read from BigQuery which is purely iterative

Comment: Use a divide by two debug strategy. Time how fast you can read from the source. Time how fast you can write to the destination.

Answer (score 1):

We also have a need to get data from BigQuery into PubSub and we do so using Dataflow. I've just looked at one of the jobs we ran today and we loaded 3.4million rows in about 5 minutes (so ~11000 rows per second).

Our Dataflow jobs are written in java but you could write them in python if you wish. Here is the code for the pipeline I described above:

```java
package com.ourcompany.pipelines;

import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineResult;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubMessage;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Description;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Validation.Required;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * The {@code BigQueryEventReplayer} pipeline runs a supplied SQL query
 * against BigQuery, and sends the results one-by-one to PubSub
 * The query MUST return a column named 'json', it is this column
 * (and ONLY this column) that will be sent onward. The column must be a String type
 * and should be valid JSON.
 */
public class BigQueryEventReplayer {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BigQueryEventReplayer.class);

  /**
   * Options for the BigQueryEventReplayer. See descriptions for more info
   */
  public interface Options extends PipelineOptions {
    @Description("SQL query to be run."
        + "An SQL string literal which will be run 'as is'")
    @Required
    ValueProvider<String> getBigQuerySql();

    void setBigQuerySql(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Description("The name of the topic which data should be published to. "
        + "The name should be in the format of projects/<project-id>/topics/<topic-name>.")
    @Required
    ValueProvider<String> getOutputTopic();

    void setOutputTopic(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Description("The ID of the BigQuery dataset targeted by the event")
    @Required
    ValueProvider<String> getBigQueryTargetDataset();

    void setBigQueryTargetDataset(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Description("The ID of the BigQuery table targeted by the event")
    @Required
    ValueProvider<String> getBigQueryTargetTable();

    void setBigQueryTargetTable(ValueProvider<String> value);

    @Description("The SourceSystem attribute of the event")
    @Required
    ValueProvider<String> getSourceSystem();

    void setSourceSystem(ValueProvider<String> value);

  }

  /**
   * Takes the data from the TableRow and prepares it for the PubSub, including
   * adding attributes to ensure the payload is routed correctly.
   */
  public static class MapQueryToPubsub extends DoFn<TableRow, PubsubMessage> {
    private final ValueProvider<String> targetDataset;
    private final ValueProvider<String> targetTable;
    private final ValueProvider<String> sourceSystem;

    MapQueryToPubsub(
        ValueProvider<String> targetDataset, 
        ValueProvider<String> targetTable, 
        ValueProvider<String> sourceSystem) {
      this.targetDataset = targetDataset;
      this.targetTable = targetTable;
      this.sourceSystem = sourceSystem;
    }

    /**
     * Entry point of DoFn for Dataflow.
     */
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      TableRow row = c.element();
      if (!row.containsKey("json")) {
        logger.warn("table does not contain column named 'json'");
      }
      Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
      attributes.put("sourceSystem", sourceSystem.get());
      attributes.put("targetDataset", targetDataset.get());
      attributes.put("targetTable", targetTable.get());
      String json = (String) row.get("json");
      c.output(new PubsubMessage(json.getBytes(), attributes));
    }
  }

  /**
   * Run the pipeline. This is the entrypoint for running 'locally'
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Parse the user options passed from the command-line
    Options options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(Options.class);
    run(options);
  }

  /**
   * Run the pipeline. This is the entrypoint that GCP will use
   */
  public static PipelineResult run(Options options) {

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    pipeline.apply("Read from BigQuery query",
        BigQueryIO.readTableRows().fromQuery(options.getBigQuerySql()).usingStandardSql().withoutValidation()
            .withTemplateCompatibility())
        .apply("Map data to PubsubMessage",
            ParDo.of(
                new MapQueryToPubsub(
                    options.getBigQueryTargetDataset(),
                    options.getBigQueryTargetTable(),
                    options.getSourceSystem()
                )
            )
        )
        .apply("Write message to PubSub", PubsubIO.writeMessages().to(options.getOutputTopic()));

    return pipeline.run();
  }
}
```

This pipeline requires that each row retrieved from BigQuery is a JSON document, something that can easily be achieved using [TO_JSON_STRING](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#to_json_string).

I know this might look rather daunting to some (it kinda does to me I admit) but it will get you the throughput that you require!

You can ignore this part:

```java
      Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
      attributes.put("sourceSystem", sourceSystem.get());
      attributes.put("targetDataset", targetDataset.get());
      attributes.put("targetTable", targetTable.get());
```

that's just some extra attributes we add to the pubsub message purely for our own use.

Comment: That was also one of my ideas, actually pleased that someone else validated it :) going to try it out

Comment: How did it work out?

Comment: much faster :) I got the script running and also took out the process from composer/airflow and isolated it (safer also to run in memory as much as it can with batches)

Answer (score 1):

Use Pub/Sub Batch Messages. This allows your code to batch multiple messages into a single call to the Pub/Sub service.

Example code from Google ([link](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#batching)):

```
from concurrent import futures
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

# TODO(developer)
# project_id = "your-project-id"
# topic_id = "your-topic-id"

# Configure the batch to publish as soon as there are 10 messages
# or 1 KiB of data, or 1 second has passed.
batch_settings = pubsub_v1.types.BatchSettings(
    max_messages=10,  # default 100
    max_bytes=1024,  # default 1 MB
    max_latency=1,  # default 10 ms
)
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(batch_settings)
topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)
publish_futures = []

# Resolve the publish future in a separate thread.
def callback(future: pubsub_v1.publisher.futures.Future) -> None:
    message_id = future.result()
    print(message_id)

for n in range(1, 10):
    data_str = f"Message number {n}"
    # Data must be a bytestring
    data = data_str.encode("utf-8")
    publish_future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
    # Non-blocking. Allow the publisher client to batch multiple messages.
    publish_future.add_done_callback(callback)
    publish_futures.append(publish_future)

futures.wait(publish_futures, return_when=futures.ALL_COMPLETED)

print(f"Published messages with batch settings to {topic_path}.")
```

Comment: I am already using code similar to that and it is very slow (sorry in my question I over simplified it)

Comment: @Randomize - Your question does not show batch processing. Update your question with the code you are using.

Comment: I updated the code, that is what I am running at the moment