# Can you get data from a Big Query table to an outside stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Because of companies policies, we have a lot of information that we need as input inserted into a BigQuery table that we need to SELECT from.

My problem is that doing a select directly into this table and trying to run a process (a virtual machine, etc) is prone to errors and reworking. If my process stops, I need to run the query again and reprocess everything.

Is there a way to export data from Big Query to a Kinesis-like stream (I'm more familiar with AWS)?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for this Google Cloud service ? https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs

Comment: I don't know what kinesis is but I assume its a streaming/queuing type thing. Similar to that, we get data from BigQuery and for each row we create an message on a pubsub topic (also a streaming/queuing type thing). We use Dataflow to do this - i.e. write a Dataflow job that issues the query and then converts each row into a message that gets published to pubsub.

Comment: I've previously shared some code here that demonstrates how we do this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72875850/201657

Comment: Thank you all for the heads ups, PubSub seems very similar to Kinesis, I'm gonna take a look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataFlow + PubSub seems to be the way to go for this kind of issue.

Thank you jamiet!